# Update child object in Mongodb using c# driver

Tags: .net, mongodb

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5882ffbe553f7c3f043fbfdf"),
  "AuditLog": null,
  "Name": "Test",
  "UserId": ObjectId("5839a1b8be46463ebc640cdc"),
  "Address": {
    "AddresType": null,
    "Address1": "S.S",
    "Address2": "Hy",
    "City": "Hyd",
    "Pincode": "50072",
    "IsActive": true,
    "Latitude": 17.497556,
    "Longitude": 78.386541
  }
}
```

I want to update the address object using _id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something if you have the right set up. Below code finds the document with `filter` and builds the address embedded doc with `update` and executes `UpdateOne` with `filter` and `update` to update the address type of address doc.

```
var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("Id", new ObjectId("5882ffbe553f7c3f043fbfdf"));
var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set("Address.AddresType", "Home");
var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

Comment: That way is worked for me. Is there any way to update entire object in single query using LINQ. or using ReplaceOneAsync method

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257013/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-2-0-update-document

Comment: var filter = Builders<Users>.Filter.Eq("_Id", id);                                    var result = await MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, <userobjec>, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });  it will update the entire user object but i want update only address object in user

Comment: did you try `var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set("Address", addressobj);` ?