# How to update but not replace a document using updateOne() of the MongoDB-driver for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

### Situation:

I have an existing collection of documents in a MongoDB in which I want to **update the fields of a specific document with the fields of an incoming document**.
The incoming document has the same class as the documents in the collection, but not all of its fields are set, i.e. some fields are null.
Now, I don't want to replace the entire document in the collection, neither do I want to replace all fields, but **I want to replace only those fields which are not null and keep the rest as is**.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30259242/3692004) describes how to replace an entire document. I got this working with this code:

```
public void Update(string id, MyDoc docIn) => _docs.ReplaceOne(doc =>  scan.Id.Equals(ObjectId.Parse(id)), docIn);
```

In order to update individual fields in the document, [the docs suggest creating an "Update Operator Expressions Document"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#updateone-behavior-aggregation-pipeline).

### My question:

Does this mean that I have to write my own function turning my incoming document into such an "Update Operator Expressions Document" or is there a more convenient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already said, using an Update Operator is the way to go.
The idea is to use a filter and use a **Reflection** of an Object that goes through the Properties.

You can modify the Update and Filter Function as you want.

```
using System.Reflection;

public void Update(string id, MyDoc docIn) 
   => _docs.UpdateOne(doc =>  doc.Id.Equals(ObjectId.Parse(id)), UpdateDocument(docIn);

public UpdateDefinition<myDoc> UpdateDocument(myDoc docIn) 
{
    var builder = Builders<MyDoc>.Update.Set(u => u.Id, docIn.Id);
    foreach(PropertyInfo prop in docIn.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
         var value = docIn.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(docIn,null);
         if ((prop.Name != "Id") & (value != null))
         {
              builder = builder.Set(prop.Name, value);
         }
    }
    return builder;
}
```